# How to choose the Owner Name field in Lightning data table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

```
({
    method2 : function(component,event,helper){
        component.set("v.mycolumns",[{label: 'Subject ', fieldName: 'Subject', type: 'string'},
                                  {label: 'Priority', fieldName: 'Priority', type: 'list'},
                                  {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'list'},
                                   {label: 'Createddate', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'Date'},
                                   {label: 'Owner Name', fieldName: 'Task.Owner', type: 'String'} ] );

        var action =component.get("c.fetchTasklist");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
             action.setParams({
        });
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") { 
        component.set("v.Tasklist", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually nested properties are not supported by [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable) yet. But we can achieve it by adding the nested properties on the main object as a property like below:

```
({
  method2 : function(component,event,helper){
    component.set("v.mycolumns",[{label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'Subject', type: 'string'},
                              {label: 'Priority', fieldName: 'Priority', type: 'list'},
                              {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', type: 'list'},
                               {label: 'Createddate', fieldName: 'CreatedDate', type: 'Date'},
                               {label: 'Owner Name', fieldName: 'TaskOwner', type: 'String'} ] );

    var action = component.get("c.fetchTasklist");

    /* It should be outside the callback and before the enqueue method call, and no need to do this if there is no parameter to pass. */
    action.setParams({}); 

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
      var state = response.getState();
      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        var taskList = response.getReturnValue();
        taskList.forEach(function(task){
          try{
            task['TaskOwner'] = task.Task.Owner; /* You can adjust the field name here. So here basically we are populating the nested property on the main object. */
          }catch(e){}
        });
        component.set("v.Tasklist", taskList);
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
});
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! After adjusting the field name to Task['Owner']['Name'], it worked for me.

Comment: @RajaShekarReddy, glad to know that it worked for you, Yes, that I have already mentioned in the comment that you have to adjust the fields here.

Comment: Is there a way to display phone field from task object in  lightning:datatable .After querying the field like who.phone in soql.

Comment: @RajaShekarReddy yes in the same way.

Comment: @ itzmukeshy7     Task['who']['phone']  this is how i tried but i didn't worked.

Comment: @RajaShekarReddy look we have to make sure that we are send the data from apex and we are using the fields in right order like parent.child.child etc. And you can also add check for null.